# Add more stringfields when button is pressed in wtform?

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

im trying to create a simple form where when I hit the "add" button, another stringfield is shown for me to add more data to. It currently works, but it only adds one field, and I can't add anymore...what am I doing wrong here?

```
    from wtforms import Form, StringField, validators,SubmitField
from flask import Flask,request,redirect,Response,render_template
import os

class RegistrationForm(Form):
    username = StringField('Username')
    add_button = SubmitField('SUBMIT')

data = True
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.environ['KEY']
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        pass
    return render_template('index.html', form=form)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

this is the HTML side

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="/">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    {{ form.username() }}
    <input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="True">
    <br>
    {% if request.form['submit_button'] == 'True': %}
        {{form.username()}}

    {% endif %}

    <input type=submit>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```